# Is there any way I can simplify this snippet of code?

Tags: c++

I feel like this snippet of code can be simplified and done a little cleaner. (No this is not an assignment, I'm not a student.)

**m_configured** is a temporary boolean I'm using, I don't need to use it.
**Load()** is a function to initialize all the registers on the board I'm working on.
**Unload()** undoes everything Load does.

I did not want to use a loop, because I just want this routine to happen once. i.e Load -- Failed --> Unload --> Load -- Failed Again --> Stop there, don't try again.

```cpp
        bool m_configured = Load();

        if (!m_configured)
        {
            xlog_info("Failed to start board. Trying again..");
            Unload();
            m_configured = Load();
            if(!m_configured)
                xlog_error("Failed to start board.");
        }

        if (m_configured)
        {
            xlog_info("Board Started");
        }
```

Update/Clarification: This code is in a constructor function.

Comment: Should have clarified, this is a snippet of code in the constructor and the m_configured is declared in the constructor for the purpose it is used here for. It's not a global.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to simplify it (you do not specify why you want to) - you could write it something like this:

```
m_configured = Load() || (Unload() && Load());
if( !m_configured )
  xlog_error("Failed to start board.");

 xlog_info("Board Started");
```

Assuming that your xlog_error() function stops the program, and that Unload() returns whether or not unloading succeeded.

Comment: Only issue is that a load failing the first time is not caught. Only if it fails twice.

Comment: Yes, you could add a seperate logging statement for that if that's significant for the use case. Just add it before Unload() in the parenthesis...